# Android FragmentPagerAdapter getter for fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, weak-references, fragmentpageradapter

I want to get the instance of a fragment from the list used in `FragmentPagerAdapter`

What i did is,

```
padap = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private List<Fragment> fragments;

public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    Log.e("MyPagerAdapter","inside MyPagerAdapter");
    this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(new FragmentBlue());
//  fragments.add(new FragmentPink());
}

public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
}
```

in onCreate, after setting pageradapter to viewpager, i get the instance using the `getFragment` method

```
mPinkFragment = padap.getFragment(1);
```

This will return the 2nd fragment, FragmentPink to the `global variable mPinkFragment`

The problem is, after some seconds say 3 seconds of idle , if i check (using runnable postDelayed)

```
if(mPinkFragment == null){
            Log.e(TAG,"mPinkFragment is null, trying from adapter");
            mPinkFragment = padap.getFragment(1);
            if(mPinkFragment == null)
                Log.e(TAG,"Still null");


        }
```

i see `mPinkFragment is null, trying from adapter` but not `Still null`.

Similarly happens for wherever accessing the members of PinkFragment.

---

**My questions**

1 ) How do i retain the objects instance? Do i need to use WeakReference?? If so, how can i?

2 ) If i add new fragment, say FragmentGreen from MAinActivity using getFragmentManager.beginTransaction call, will this be added to viewpagerAdapter's fragments list?

Thanks in advance!